# Regex, get multiple occurrences

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how to get multiple occurrences from a regex.

```
$str = "Some validations <IF TEST>firstValue</IF> in <IF OK>secondValue</IF> end of string.";
$do = preg_match("/<IF(.*)>.*<\/IF>/i", $str, $matches);
```

This is what I've done so far. It works if I have only 1 , but if I have more it doesn't return the right values. Here is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => firstValue in secondValue [1] => TEST>firstValue in
```

I need to get the "TEST" and the "OK" values.

**EDIT**: I've brought the modifications suggested, thanks a lot it works fine ! However, I am now trying to add a elsif parameter and can't get it to work well. Here is what I've done:

```
$do = preg_match_all("~<IF([^<>]+)>([^<>]+)(</IF>|<ELSEIF([^<>]+)>([^<>]+)</IF>)~", $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

and the results is

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
           (
              [0] => firstValuesecondValue 
              [1] => TEST 
              [2] => firstValue 
              [3] => secondValue 
              [4] => TEST1 
              [5] => secondValue 
           ) 
    [1] => Array 
           ( 
               [0] => thirdValue 
               [1] => OK 
               [2] => thirdValue 
               [3] => 
           ) 
)
```

Is there a way to make my array more clean ? It has many elements which are useless like the [0][4] etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the regex more specific. The `.*` that you are using should either be less greedy, or better yet disallow other angle brackets:

```
~<IF([^<>]+)>([^<>]+)</IF>~i
```

More importantly, you should use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), not just [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match).

```
preg_match_all("~<IF([^<>]+)>([^<>]+)</IF>~i", $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

That'll give you a nested array like:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <IF TEST>firstValue</IF>
        [1] =>  TEST
        [2] => firstValue
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => <IF OK>secondValue</IF>
        [1] =>  OK
        [2] => secondValue
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers pointing out that you should use `preg_match_all` are correct.

But there is another problem: the `.*` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) by default. This will cause it to match both tags in a single match, so you need to make the star [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) (i.e. lazy):

```
/<IF(.*?)>.*?<\/IF>/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$string = "Some validations <IF TEST>firstValue</IF> in <IF OK>secondValue</IF> end of string.";
$regex = "/<IF (.*?)>.*?<\/IF>/i";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

You regex is good but you have to use the non-greedy mode adding the `?` char and use the `preg_match_all()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-greedy match `.*?` and `preg_match_all` for this purpose.